# Getting no beans found errors when Custom Repo class extends with JpaRepository

Tags: java, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

```
    I am creating a simple CRUD application using spring boot and hibernate with ajax requests from jsp page. i got working this to the controller and after when i extend my Repo class with JpaRepository i am geting no beans found errors. 

    i have tried to enable entity manager in web config class an then i also get no beans found for entity manager.

    This is my controller class


 @Controller
    public class EmployeeController {

           @Autowired
           private EmployeeRepo employeeRepo;

           @GetMapping("/")
           public String employeeForm() {
              return "employeeForm";
           }

           @PostMapping(value = "/saveEmployee", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
           @ResponseBody
           public boolean saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute @Valid Employee employee, BindingResult result) {
               Employee save = employeeRepo.save(employee);
               return true;
           }

        }

    this is my custom repository 
    public interface EmployeeRepo extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> {

    }


    this is my web config class
```

@Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.boraji.tutorial.spring.controller" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.boraji.tutorial.spring.repo" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.boraji.tutorial.spring.repo", entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory")
public class WebConfig extends  WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Bean
   public InternalResourceViewResolver resolver() {
      InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
      resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
      resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return resolver;
   }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator(){
       return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
   }

}


    this is my webapp initializer class


    public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

       @Override
       protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
          return new Class[] {};
       }

       @Override
       protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
          return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
       }

       @Override
       protected String[] getServletMappings() {
          return new String[] { "/" };
       }
    }
```

this is the error

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'employeeRepo'; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeRepo': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7dc21c89' of type 
 [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7dc21c89': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

Comment: add `@Repository` on `EmployeeRepo` class